# Problem with a continuous and *almost* monotonic function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

### Problem

> Let $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Suppose that for all x in $[a,b)$ and for all $\delta>0$ there exists a $y \in (x, x+\delta)\cap [a,b]$ such that $f(x)<f(y)$. The goal is to prove that f is monotonically increasing.

### Conclusion analysis

$f$ is monotonically increasing on its domain, if and only if $$\forall x\in [a,b]\  \forall \epsilon>0 \ ( f(x+\epsilon)>f(x)).$$

### Hypotheses analysis

What this given property says about $f$ is that given any point on the domain, except the boundary point $b$ and given any distance to the right of $x$ there always exists an intermediate point $y$ for which $f$ assumes a value larger than $x$.

### Attempt at proof

Let x be a point of the domain, **not** $b$, and furthermore let $\epsilon>0$ be given. I need to show that $f(x+\epsilon)>f(x)$.
I naturally choose $\delta = \epsilon$ in my hypothesis. I am assured by the function property of the existence of a $y\in (x, x+\epsilon)\cap[a,b]$ for which $f(y)>f(x)$.

I suspect that here I need to use the fact that $f$ is continuous in order to show explicitly that
$f(x+\epsilon) > f(y)$, so that I can conclude the proof.

What I need at this point is a hint. Furhtermore, the problem forced me to consider two seperate cases
with $x\neq b$ and $x=b$; I wonder if the boundary point $x=b$ possess a significant problem down the line.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $f$ is not increasing. Then there are $u, v \in [a,b]$ such that $u < v$ and $f(u) \ge f(v)$. Since $f$ is continuous, it attains a maximum on $[u,v]$. That is, there exists $\zeta \in [u,v]$ such that $f(z) \le f(\zeta)$ for all $z \in [u,v]$.

$\zeta = v$ is impossible: In that case $f(z) \le f(v) \le f(u)$ for all $z \in[u,v]$ which contradicts the assumption if we take $x = u$ and $\delta = v-u$.

Hence we must have $\zeta \in [u,v)$. But this contradicts the assumption if we take $x = \zeta$ and $\delta = v-\zeta$.

Comment: Contradiction: always there to save Reason when all else fails.Thanks Paul.